# Can we have auto AspectRatio preset for output files from AWS Elastic Transcoder?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, video, aspect-ratio, amazon-elastic-transcoder

I'm working on AWS **Elastic Transcoder** using PHP API. I would like to have the video output to have the same **AspectRatio** as the input video.

Do we need a custom preset for that? I tried seeing the options. But, there is no option for auto **AspectRation**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try creating a custom preset and use a "Sizing Policy" that preserves aspect ration, such as Fit, keep and ShrinkToFit.
"Display Aspect Ratio" should be set to auto.

There are many combinations, so run few experiments. see
[Sizing Policy](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elastictranscoder/latest/developerguide/preset-settings.html#preset-settings-video-sizing-policy)